# How do I safely turn a name into a 'sanitised alias' in a MySQL view?

Tags: mysql

I've got a table with real names, e.g. "Matt Smith", but I need to convert them to be used as URL paths in a web app. "Matt Smith" would become "matt-smith", "Danny O'Brien" would become "danny-obrien", etc.

I need to lowercase, strip special characters, and replace spaces with dashes.

I know I can do this to replace spaces:

`SELECT REPLACE( table.field, ' ', '-' ) FROM table;`

And I know there's a LOWER() function as well.

What I don't know is:

1. How to strip special characters
2. How to combine all three into one SQL query that actually works
3. If it's possible to make it work automatically when I create the view, and for it to keep working as new rows are added via the web app

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Comment: [Another take](https://www.ryadel.com/en/mysql-function-query-convert-string-slug-readable-url-permalinks/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using MySQL 8+, then `REGEXP_REPLACE` is one option:

```
SELECT
    LOWER(REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(field, '[^A-Za-z0-9]', ''), ' ', '-')) AS alias
FROM yourTable;
```

The innermost call to `REGEXP_REPLACE` strips off all non alphanumeric characters.